# vertical center text near slider

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am just starting out with learning html/css so I bought a template and installed wordpress and planned to play with it a bit. However, I got stuck on this thing and it's pretty annyoing that i can't figure it out.
On my page there is the main slider and the event slider beneath it. I would like to center the text "NE events" and "View all events" both vertical and horizontal with the slider.

I have tried to center via various methods, but I failed. The only one that would work is setting up a margin-top, but it would not be responsive. Also, I can put everything in a div and align it because it will mess up my slider's element alignment.

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
<p style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">NE Events</p>
</div>

<div class="wpb_wrapper">
<---slider shortcode--->
</div>

<div class="wpb_wrapper">
<a href="#">View All</a>
</div>
```

first element is 1/12 columns of the website
second element is 10/12 columns
thirds is 1/12

Comment: Please, read how to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting them in the same places they are now? I guess I am a little confused when you say to center them vertial and horizontal with the slider.

Adding the following css will make them center vertically with the accordian slider in between.

```
.vc_col-sm-1 {
    padding-top: 27px;
}
```

This just adds a little padding to push the text down a little bit, so if the slider images get larger, you would have to also increase this padding. If you want to remove the padding on the mobile version you can put the same code but 0px instead of 27 but it would need to be placed within the screen size media query in the CSS so it only kicks in when the screen is smaller.... like a phone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solution is correct, but as I have mentioned: is there any other better solution to this?

Comment: Were you wanting it to be displayed differently than just that? I guess if I had a better idea where you were wanting the text to be I could try and figure something out... but if thats what you were wanting, it would probably be your best solution.

Comment: Yea, that was what i wanted. Well ok then... I'll go ahead with this solution :). thanks

Comment: The other options are going to have a similar effect where it just pushes the text down. If the size of the area is changing and it needs to adjust there are other options, but not as simple and if this works, it is going to be your best bet. What is it about adding padding that you are trying to avoid? I am sure there are options to fix the issues the padding causes

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can set a height for the 1/12 columns or add another class so that in won't affect other columns. In your case i think it's about 80px high. Then set a line-height equal to your column height. This method is for one-liner text only.

```
.addtnl-class {
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
}
```

There are lot's of way to automatically vertically center align your text in a div. Just search google and you'll find them.  :)